# Geolocating a PCD

Tags: point-cloud, pcd

I have some simulation software that generates values in real 3D space. Because the output is in real space, it's being stored in the LAS format. However, LAS is not really designed to store arbitrary data and its point formats usually include irrelevant fields (e.g. return number, which has no meaning in this application,) so it's not a perfect fit.

PCD, on the other hand is wonderfully straightforward and its *records* are extensible. But it seems to me that its *header* is not. Is there a good way to store the projection information (or any metadata whatsoever) in PCD? I'm close to overloading the VIEWPOINT entry, but I think that would be super unclear to anyone unfamiliar with the generating software, plus it still would be pretty ambiguous.